# How do I use gdal_proximity.py from the QGIS python console?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

How do I run gdal_proximity.py from the QGIS python console?

Answer (score 2):

With the Python processing module (look at [Using processing algorithms from the console](http://qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html))

1) look at the Processing Toolbox, there is a proximity command [GDAL] Analysis/proximity:

[image]

2) in the Python console

```
>>> import processing
>>> # list of algorithms (a lot ...)
>>> processing.alglist()
.....
pct2rgb---------------------------------------------->gdalogr:pct2rgb
proximity-------------------------------------------->gdalogr:proximity
rgb2pct---------------------------------------------->gdalogr:rgb2pct
......
>>> processing.alglist('proximity')
Grid proximity buffer-------------------------------->saga:gridproximitybuffer
Proximity grid--------------------------------------->saga:proximitygrid
proximity-------------------------------------------->gdalogr:proximity
```

and

```
>>> # help for the parameters of the proximity algorithm
>>> processing.alghelp("gdalogr:proximity")
ALGORITHM: proximity
src_filename <ParameterRaster>
values <ParameterString>
maxdist <ParameterNumber>
nodata <ParameterNumber>
distunits <ParameterSelection>
fixed_buf_val <ParameterNumber>
dst_filename <OutputRaster>
  distunits(distunits)
0 -  GEO
1 - PIXEL
```

So you use:

```
>>> processing.runalg("gdalogr:proximity","your_src_filename",yourvalues,yourmaxdist,yournodata,"GEO",yourfixed_buf_val,"yourdst_filename")
```

Comment: `alglist()` works okay, but when I try to run `listalgs()`, I get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'listalgs'"...